# Add link to network and chat profiles

Tags: script, users, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

The [recent design update to the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/295232) removed the [ability to easily navigate to a user's network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372599/295232), even though they chose to [hide their profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-communities). Since that functionality is not always used for benign purposes, I wrote a userscript to bring it back, and add another profile link (to the chat profile) as well. This should make moderation a little bit easier.

#### Download

The script can be installed via [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/add-network-profile-link/add-network-profile-link.user.js); source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/add-network-profile-link/add-network-profile-link.user.js).

#### Platform

Tested with Violentmonkey in Firefox on macOS, but it's likely to work on all browsers and platforms. (Please let me know if it doesn't!)

### Contact

Post a comment or answer here, or create an issue/pull request on GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the Community user's profile on any site. For that user, can it be hardcoded to link to `/users/-1` on the site's respective chat server?

Comment: @gparyani it was on my to-do list to fix this, but CodyGray got to it earlier ... it's fixed in version 1.2.